# Settting default import/export path Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to build like some sort of input where you can set an import/export default path. To demonstrate what I'm trying to build I will use Chrome's **default download location** as example.

[image: Chrome's reference]

If anyone have any idea how I can start tackling this it will be very helpful.
Btw, I want to build this with reactjs

UPDATE:

When you click on the **CHANGE** button it will open the file system where you can set the path where the downloads will go. I want to do exactly that. I'm building a report UI where you can export/import reports.

Comment: I read your question about 3 times, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you please expand?

Comment: Sorry @Chris I've added more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: You cannot read the default download path (or anything system related) in javascript because of security reasons (just imagine what malicious sites could do with that info).